# Большой запрос в MySQL (php)

Tags: php, sql, vkontakte-api, mysqli

Есть группа в ВКонтакте, я получаю список всех участников группы и записываю их идентификаторы в базу данных.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
$paramerts = http_build_query($arguments);

start:

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?$paramerts"));

$items = $request->response->items;

foreach ($items as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 999) {

        $arguments['offset'] += 1000;

        $response[] = $value;

        goto start;

    } else {

        $response[] = $value;

    }

}

$sql = '';

foreach ($response as $user_id) {

    $sql .= '(' . $user_id . ',' . $group_id . '),';

}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

mysqli_query($connection, 'INSERT `group_members` (`user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES ' . $sql);
```

При добавлении группы с 100 000 участников, проблем нет. Но если эта группа с 1 000 000, то массив создаётся за 50 секунд а запрос в базу данных в итоге не выполняется. Но есть группы и с 10 000 000 участников.

В дальнейшем мне ещё придётся получать из БД список участников, сравнивать с новым список и обновлять его новыми участниками. Так я смогу узнать новых подписчиков группы. Примерно так работает приложение в ВКонтакте "Дезертир".

Как сделать обработку больших групп?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких ресурсоемких операций есть типовое решение - выполнение задания в фоновом режиме. Т.е. Вы создаете некий код, который обрабатывается не как запрос браузера к вэб-серверу, а помещается в очередь заданий, а затем выполняется обработчиком в фоновом режиме. Самостоятельно "велосипедить" не рекомендую, как-то сам вынужден был частичную функциональность реализовать - умаялся. В качестве примера решения привожу [ссылку на аналогичную функциональность, предоставляемую Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues). Можно воспользоваться решениями от любых других фреймворков.

При этом такое большое задание, как обработка 10 млн записей, можно разбить на части и реализовать в виде нескольких заданий, каждое из которых обрабатывает свою часть общего объема. Код один и тот же, параметры для выполнения разные.

**Update**

Вы все значения вгоняете в одну строку. Для того же MySQL есть ограничение на максимальную длину запроса. Желательно грузить данные в базу порциями. Например, каждые 1000 (или 10 000) обработанных пользователей оформлять отдельным оператором SQL и инсертить. Если для Вас важна целостность данных - оформите всю операцию добавления данных в виде транзакции, и завершайте транзакцию после последнего инсерта. Тогда в случае сбоя в работе скрипта в базу не попадет ничего, а в случае успешного завершения - одномоментно появятся все загруженные записи.

Comment: Взял транзакции на заметку. Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда возьмите на заметку и другой прием - _подготовленные запросы_ (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). Один раз выражение готовите, а в цикле вместо того, чтобы помещать данные в массив, - выполняете это выражение с данными. Скорость обработки подготовленного выражения в MySQL вырастает на порядок, при этом все записи добавляются по одной. Можно также все это "завернуть" в транзакцию.